# Google map api не отображается в модальном окне при открытии

Tags: javascript, jquery

`Google map api` не отображается в модальном окне при открытии. Если изменить размеры окна браузера, то карта появляется. Пробовал `resize`, не помогло.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // google Карта
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  var address = "Киев";

  function initMap() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = {
      lat: 200.363,
      lng: 300.044
    };
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeControl: true,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
      },
      navigationControl: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);


    if (geocoder) {
      geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
      }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: '<b>' + address + '</b>',
              size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: results[0].geometry.location,
              map: map,
              title: address
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });

          } else {
            alert("- Произошла ошибка");
          }
        } else {
          alert("- Произошла ошибка: " + status);
        }
      });
    }
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Там на официальной страницы гугла написано, что если элемент был скрыт при инициализации карты, то надо вызвать метод `update`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko как это и где сделать не подскажешь?

Answer (score 0):

Если карта была скрыта, то после ее показа надо ее обновить.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/66uqzaeb/).

После открытия модального окна выполните данный код:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Comment: пробовал , не выходит.

Comment: На jsfiddle смотрели? Попробуйте обернуть вызов `resize` в `setTimeout`.

Comment: да уже нет желания пробовать, много времени потратил на это.

Comment: @МаксимС Эх, мне бы так - нет желания, не исправляешь баг. Красота!